# Bokeh: How to Create Internal Hyperlinks

Tags: python, bokeh

I want to have a sort of Table of Contents where I click the hyperlink text "Plot 1" and am taken to a plot of Plot 1.

How do I do this?

I can create a button with a customJS callback to move me to that section as well, in that case, how do I move the page and how do I know where to move the page to in Javascript?

Jupyter Notebook Equivalent: https://sebastianraschka.com/Articles/2014_ipython_internal_links.html

Comment: Do you mean a link to things *inside* plots (i.e. not to separate plots)? If so I don't know that this is possible. Bokeh renders on HTML canvas which is just a big opaque object, as far as the DOM is concerned there is no way to refer to things "inside" it. Bokeh knows the pixel coordinates of things inside the canvas but I am not sure how that would help you.

Comment: @bigreddot no, to separate plots, I want to jump to a plot when I click, say a button, ideally I'd like to be able to click a hyperlink with the text "Plot 1" and be taken to the corresponding plot.

Comment: There's definitely nothing built in to Bokeh for this. You would need to embed the Bokeh content in a template that has anchor tags where you want (i.e., above where a plot is embedded) and then construct a list of links to those anchor tags.

Comment: @bigreddot I tried giving the bokeh figure objects tags/names/id and then using things like 'find' from https://docs.bokeh.org/en/latest/docs/reference/core/query.html or getElementsByTagName, but neither gave me the tags/ids/names I had set. Any thoughts?

Comment: Those are not related to the DOM, they are properties of Bokeh objects. There is no way to automate this. You will have to create a template that has the anchors you want (up front), and then embed Bokeh content right where those anchors are.

Comment: Yup, thanks, will try that.